# How to make a generic query for search page?

Tags: sql-server, search

I have a Order Search page where user can enter any search criteria and submit. 
If if clicks submit without entering any criteria we should show all orders. 
If users enters orderId we should show only that respective order. 
If user enters date range and status we should show orders with that selected status in selected date range.

I tried as shown.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE ( OrderNumber ='' OR OrderNumber ='212' )
AND ( (OrderDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2012-10-10') 
OR (OrderDate BETWEEN '' AND '')  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check if the field has the value AND if the field does not have the value. You will always get all records regardless. You will need to pull the values out into a variable. Unless you are writing dynamic SQL; if that is the case then you would only add to the where clause if you intend to filter...

```
DECLARE @OrderNumber VARCHAR, @StartDate VARCHAR, @EndDate VARCHAR

SET @OrderNumber = '212'
SET @StartDate = '2010-01-01'
SET @EndDate = '2012-01-01'

SELECT  * 
FROM    dbo.Orders 
WHERE   (@OrderNumber ='' OR OrderNumber = @OrderNumber) 
AND     (@StartDate = '' OR OrderDate >= @StartDate)
AND     (@EndDate = '' OR OrderDate <= @EndDate)
```

Comment: Using `NULL` to indicate an unspecified value may be helpful.  An empty string may be an appropriate value, e.g. I want to find the easy orders where `ShippingNotes` is empty.

Comment: Yes accounting for `NULL` does complicate things a little, but in reading into the OP I see that he is using empty strings. If OP wants to pass `NULL` into the command then you simple change `@Variable = ''` to `@Variable IS NULL` and the rest is the same. Of course on the flip side you might want to isolate `NULL` records. In that case the where clause would resemble `COALESCE(@Variable, 'dummystring') = COALESCE(FieldName, 'dummystring')`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this complete [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html) from Erland and in particular the heading "[Umachandar's Bag of Tricks](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#Umachandar)"

Also check [Implementing a Dynamic WHERE Clause](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-a-dynamic-where-clause)

Extract from the above article showing how to make use of COALESCE to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @Cus_Name varchar(30),
                  @Cus_City varchar(30),
                  @Cus_Country varchar(30)

SET @Cus_Name = NULL
SET @Cus_City = 'Paris'
SET @Cus_Country = NULL

SELECT Cus_Name,
               Cus_City,
               Cus_Country
FROM Customers
WHERE Cus_Name = COALESCE(@Cus_Name,Cus_Name) AND
      Cus_City = COALESCE(@Cus_City,Cus_City) AND
      Cus_Country = COALESCE(@Cus_Country,Cus_Country)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a very simple query
declare @ordernumber int = null
SELECT * FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE
(@ordernumber is null or (OrderNumber IS NOT NULL AND OrderNumber IN (@ordernumber)))
AND ( (OrderDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2012-10-10') OR (OrderDate BETWEEN '' AND '')  )

Although this query is simple enough but here goes the explanation : if @ordernumber is null, then it would display all the records, while for the other case it will display only the record corresponding to the passed orderid.

Comment: forgot to mention that @ordernumber is the ordernumber passed